# How to set up a race with a friend on Mario Kart 8

Tags: mario-kart-8

I know how to set up a race with random people, but I can't figure out how to set it up with my friend. I click on "Online: One Player" then "friends", then I click on my friend's name, and there is a button that says "join", but it won't let me click it. When I do all of this, my friend is online.

Answer (score -2):

Do you receive an error code? If not, i'd say you need to either reset your router and/or motem, and/or your Wii U system.